# how to log-in at windows server 2003 in amazon ec2 which bundle years ago

Tags: amazon-ec2

i had an AMI which is bundle in 2009.
but today when i try to login to it.
and want to generate new asmininstrator password it gives me console massage that
passowrd is unavailable for this instance.
What can i do to log in my instance again.
please help

Answer (score 0):

Once an existing AMI is bundled, then you can't use the same keypair to re-generate the password on an instance launched from the new AMI.  The admin password should be changed before bundling, and you can then use it to login to an instance created from the new AMI.

Comment: but i don't have that password with me. 
kindly suggest me the way to log in.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this for a while, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

The AMIs keys are based on the key-pair you use. You typically select a key-pair when you launch an AMI.

If you use the AWS web console, it is the 3rd step. You can either use an existing key-pair or create a new one. From this step:

> "Public/private key pairs allow you to securely connect to your
>   instance after it launches. To create a key pair, enter a name and
>   click Create & Download your Key Pair. You will then be prompted to
>   save the private key to your computer. Note, you only need to generate
>   a key pair once - not each time you want to deploy an Amazon EC2
>   instance."

You can view your existing key-pairs from the 'Key Pairs' section of the EC2 dashboard.

Essentially, create a new key-pair, use it to launch the AMI, and login using the private key you are given.